# Scoping association in RailsAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, associations, rails-admin

I try to scope an association so that users can't see reminders that were already sent when editing a relationship. I do however, want them to be seen in the 'show' view, but not in 'edit' view.

I can't get the scope to work on a per field basis. I can scope the entire has_many call with a proc, but that won't let me show the results on the 'show' page as it's model wide. Here's my current code, which doesn't seem to work based on the RailsAdmin wiki:

```
  group :reminders do
    label 'Reminders'
    field :reminders do
      active true

      associated_collection_scope do
        Proc.new { |scope|
          scope = scope.where(sent: false)
        }
      end

    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try throwing your code above inside of an `edit do ; end` block. So, would become:

```
edit do  
  group :reminders do
    label 'Reminders'
    field :reminders do
      active true

      associated_collection_scope do
        Proc.new { |scope|
          scope = scope.where(sent: false)
        }
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
associated_collection_cache_all true
```

It should help